# Suddenly I can't access my MongoDB through MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, connection

I've been working on development with a free Atlas cluster (I did not create this cluster) for the last week and suddenly today I get this error:

> connection < monitor > to 3.214.89.95:27017 closed

I have read online that this might have something to do with the access list, so I added my own IP to the access list + the IP of 0.0.0.0/0 like I have read online. However, none of this seems to help. (note: I use the exactly same connection string with my code on node.js and it works fine, but when I try to login using MongoDB Compass, it doesn't work). Does anyone know what this could be?